# posting a tweet via a form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ok, so I'm struggling with a form I want to use to post tweets to my twitter account.
I'm using gem 'omniauth-twitter' and gem 'twitter'.

My form is not sending it's content to Twitter.update() which lives inside products_controller.rb and I can't figure out why.

Here's the code I have so far...

from my index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag do %>
<fieldset>
    <legend>140 char limit</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="mytweet">mytweet:</label>
        <%= text_field_tag :my_tweet, params[:my_tweet] %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= submit_tag "tweet" %>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

from my products_controller.rb

```
def tweetfunc
if param[:tweet] != nil then
  Twitter.update(param[:tweet])
else
  #TODO display an error message
end
```

end

inside my routes.rb

```
controller :products do
post 'tweet' => :tweetfunc
```

end

....any ideas?

Comment: My form is not sending it's content to Twitter.update() which lives inside products_controller.rb and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

check the first line of your posted index.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag do %>
```

and out an url to your controller in there like this:

```
<%= form_tag tweet_products_path do %>
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In controller:

```
Twitter.update(params[:my_tweet]) if params[:my_tweet].present?
```

Other than that I strongly suggest you follow a REST architecture, and have a ActiveModel-compliant Tweet class, and use form builder helpers on instances of that class, ie. `for_for @tweet do |f| ...`